# Infinite iterable generator in Ceylon

Tags: ceylon

Is there an easy way in Ceylon to create an infinite iterable which generates each element by calling the same given no-args function? In other words, does the language module offer an equivalent to Java 8's [`Stream.generate(Supplier<T>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
{Value+} generator<Value>(Value() generate) => {generate()}.cycled;
```

This works because `{generate()}` is lazy.

Answer (score 1):

No this doesn't actually exist right now and I think the "Ceylonish" way would be something like this:

```
class Generator<T>(T func()) satisfies Iterable<T> {
    object iter satisfies Iterator<T> {
        next() => func();
    }
    iterator() => iter;
}
```

Also you could open a request for it on: [the language module](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon.language/issues/new)

Comment: [The FAQ says it is called "ceylonic"](http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.1/faq/#am_i_allowed_to_say_ceylonish).

Comment: That was [added almost a year after](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon-lang.org/commit/94f311119d1e50971794be225a77c18ed9b220cc) I answered that question ;)